# jquery modify each class html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I am new to jquery, it is taking me too much time to figure this out.

**HTML**

```
<div class="date">12-02-2012</div>
<div class="date">14-02-2012</div>
```

I need to save the value of the respective div in variable then change it for the respective tag.

```
var1 = '12-02-2012'
var2 = '14-02-2012'

<div class="date">12- Number(var1.split('-')[1])+1 -2012</div>
<div class="date">14- Number(var2.split('-')[1])+1 -2012</div>
```

Instead of using var1 and var2, i need it to be something like foreach element that has class="date".

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking, or what you're trying to do. Could you update your question with the HTML you're attempting to generate as a result of your logic?

Comment: This question is very unclear. So you want to insert dates into all elements that have a class attribute of `date`?

Comment: Whenever you have variables named like `var1`, `var2`, etc. they probably should be an array. That makes it easier to process them all in a loop.

Comment: sorry about the question wasn't very clear, i wanted to change any part of the date, the date html is generated with php, data extracted from db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$('div.date').each(function(){
    var date = this.innerHTML.split('-').map(Number); // convert that string into a array of numbers
    date[1] = date[1] + 1; // add +1 in the middle number
    this.innerHTML = date.join('-'); // put it back into the div
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qfqkt98r/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to understand, but from the pseudo code sample I am assuming that you want to add `1` to the second value in the string. In which case you can do this:

```js
$('.date').text(function(i, t) {
    var dateParts = t.split('-');
    dateParts[1] = ("00" + (parseInt(dateParts[1], 10) + 1)).substr(-2);
    return dateParts.join('-');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date">12-02-2012</div>
<div class="date">14-02-2012</div>
```

You could also achieve this by parsing the text value of the `div` element to a date, but that would be much more long winded as you need to dissect the date, amend the value and then put it all back together again. Note however, that if your addition ever crosses a year boundary you would need to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var NewHTML = '';
  //loop through all the divs
  $(".date").each(function(){
    //get date from div
    var datevalue = $(this).text();
    //Split date
    var dateArr = datevalue.split('-');
    
    //Create new HTML of div as per your need
    //For month part first it converted to int then added 1 and then converted to string and apended 0 before the month.
    if(parseInt(dateArr[1])<9){
      var month = (0+(parseInt(dateArr[1])+1).toString());
    }else{
      var month = ((parseInt(dateArr[1])+1).toString());
    }
    NewHTML += '<div class="date">'+dateArr[0]+'-'+month+'-'+dateArr[2]+'</div>';
  });
  $("#outcome").html(NewHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date">12-10-2012</div>
<div class="date">14-02-2012</div>

Result:<br/>

<div id="outcome"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the variables. If you give a function to `.text()` or `.html()`, it receives the old contents and returns the replacement.

```js
$("#change").click(function() {
  $(".date").text(function(i, oldtext) {
    return '12-' + (Number(oldtext.split('-')[1]) + 1) + '-2012';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date">12-02-2012</div>
<div class="date">14-02-2012</div>
<button id="change">Click</button>
```